# How do you move a dragsource with React-DND?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

How do you make the source element move with the mouse cursor using `react-dnd`?

This is what I am doing (simplified example):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {DragDropContext, DragSource} from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

@DragSource("zzzz", {beginDrag: props => ({})}, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
export class DND extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const text = this.props.isDragging ? "YAY": "DND";

    return this.props.connectDragSource(
      <div>{text}</div>
    );
  }
}

@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
export class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><DND /></div>;
  }
}

ReactDom.render(
  <Application />,
  document.getElementById('react-mount')
);
```

The text changes from `DND` to `YAY` when I click and drag it, but the div does not move to follow the mouse.

The examples I have gone through do not appear to be manually updating the targets x/y coordinates, and I assume this is managed by the library itself.  What am I missing?

### Edit:

I failed to mention this happens while emulating mobile devices in Chrome devtools.  It works as expected in desktop mode.

I'm currently looking into moving the dragsource using `DragLayer` as seen [here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-dnd-touch-backend/blob/master/examples/js/ItemPreview.jsx);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile browser not show the shadow of drag source when dragging. You need use `DragPreview` to draw the moving.

Comment: I've been emulating mobile platforms in the Chrome devtools.  It looks like the ghost _is_ created in desktop mode.  I will go learn how `DragPreview` works, thank you.